# Crossing number lemma

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, discrete-geometry

> Suppose that a simple graph $G$ on $n$ vertices drawn in the plane. Prove that if
> every edge crosses at most one another edge, then the number of edges in $G$ is at most $4n − 8$

*What I have tried:* I tried to take a graph with finite vertices let's say 12 and drew it in a criss-cross manner so that every edge have at most one crossing. Here since it not planar then it won't satisfy the Euler formula or edge requirement conditions. So I thought of removing edges one by one it won't have any crossings. And then I can apply one of the edge conditions. But it did not result in a meaningful way. Then I do not know any other approach. Could you please help me to solve this?

Cheers!!

Comment: Can you discuss where you got this bound of $4n-8$?  I see that it works for $n=8$, by constructing a "box" and putting a "cross" on all 6 sides. The result can't hold for any smaller $n$ (because $n$ choose 2 would be less than $4n-8$), so I suppose the goal is to show it works for $n\geq 8$?  Is there an easy construction for larger graphs that have exactly this number of edges?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-planar_graph#Edge_density

Comment: @BradElliott HI!.. I got this question as a part of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

For each edge $f = uv$ that crosses an edge $e$, if there are not already edges from the endpoints of $e$ to the endpoints of $f$, add them. (These edges can always be added without crossing other edges, since $f$ meets only $e$ on its path from $u$ to $v$.)

[image]

Thus we obtain a graph $H$ with (potentially) more edges than $G$.
Consider a planar subgraph $H'$ obtained by deleting one of each pair of edges that cross. $H'$ has at most $3n-6$ edges, and at most $2n - 4$ faces. Each removed edge crosses two faces of $H'$, and at most one of the removed edges appears in each face of $H'$, so there are at most $n - 2$ removed edges.